# Explanation of Disraeli's quote (The Mighty Leviathan)

Tags: meaning

At leaf 239 in the book *Sobriquets And Nicknames* (1887), it reads:

> **"Mighty Leviathan, The.** A name given to Thomas Hobbes. Disraeli, in his *Amenities of Literature*, says:-
>      The hardy paradoxes, not wholly without foundation, and the humiliating truths so mortifying to human nature, of the mighty Leviathan, whose author was little disposed to flatter his brothers, were opposed by an ideal government"

Never read the book but nevertheless I am aware of Thomas Hobbes and haps moreso the remarkable Negroid Christlike Hobgoblin saviour monarch - seen overcoming Leviathan? Anyway, *the question is*: I would love to understand the meaning behind the aforeshown *The Mighty Leviathan* but woe I hardly can. Could someone break it down for me please?

Comment: Perhaps next to the thesaurus you so melodramatically abuse there is a dictionary, which could dispel some of your doubts with respect to meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Some of your second paragraph has a lunatic or reckless feel. Is the whole thing an excuse to include the racist term "negroid"? A "leviathan" is "something or someone that is extremely large and powerful". The word is the title of Hobbes' book, derived from the sea monster of Hebrew legend. 17th century Biblical interpreters believed that the creature was named using the Hebrew words *lavah*, meaning "to couple, connect, or join", and *thannin*, meaning "a serpent or dragon", “because by his bignesse he seemes not one single creature, but a coupling of divers together; or because his scales are closed, or straitly compacted together.” This coupling is referred to poetically by Hobbes in the title of his work, and is intended to convey the idea of a political "commonwealth" whose strength is derived from the joining together of many elements (people). Disraeli nicknamed Hobbes himself the "mighty Leviathan" because of his great stature as a political writer. Note that "Disraeli" here is not Benjamin Disraeli, twice Prime Minister of the United Kingdom, but his father, the writer Isaac Disraeli.